# Including remote files in LaTeX documents

Tags: include, linux

I do all my research/thesis stuff on my local computer (Windows). Most of my big data stuff, analysis files and graphs (usually all pdf files) rest on a remote university server (Linux). Now consider my current particular situation: I have 16 pdf files (of graphs) that I need to send to my professor. Instead of sending him 16 files, I am putting all 16 of them on one page and sending that. This works nicely and is NOT the problem.

- The problem is that the pdf files are stored on the server. So if I am working on my local machine, I have to connect to FTP, download the files, and change all paths. (If I end up uploading the TeX document back to server, I have to change ALL paths to a Linux path which is very time consuming).
- Since I am using git, my current solution is to change the file on my local machine, push it to the repo, pull/sync on my server and run the tex file there. The problem with this is that I have many commits for simple changes (like a typo). I don't want this. Furthermore, running the tex file on a Linux server is new to me and I spend too much time debugging it, installing packages and so on. That's why I prefer to work on my local copy.

So basically, I am asking if there is a way to tell Linux that the file path is actually stored on a server. And to pull the files from there. I realize this may take a longer time to build. Also, I'd like a method that doesn't create a ton of temporary files (but maybe downloads the files into memory and uses that).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\newcounter{graphgroup}
\setcounter{graphgroup}{1}
\includepdfset{
  nup=3x4,
  delta=2pt 2pt,
  addtolist={
    1,figure,Graph Group \thegraphgroup,graphgroup\thegraphgroup},
  pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}\refstepcounter{graphgroup}}% remove if you want empty pages; adjust if you want something fancier
}


\begin{document}

%% PURPOSE OF DOCUMENT:
%% Use this TEX file to place graphs on paper for easy printing/viewing. This is nothing specical. 

% /home/affans/ChrommHMM/corr_

  \includepdfmerge[width=.3\paperwidth]{file1.pdf, file2.pdf, file3.pdf, ..., file16.pdf}


\end{document}
```

Comment: On GNU/Linux I would just mount the relevant directory on the server to a local mount point and treat it as local. (E.g. using `sshfs`.) I have no idea if Windows lets you do this.

Comment: Ah! That's brilliant! I can definitely mount my Linux folder on my Windows machine! But alas, the problem is that I'd like to not have to change paths wherever the file is located. But this is good progress!

Comment: Hmm, I also realized that I don't really have to use hard links. As long as my file is in the same folder, I can just specificy the file names.

Comment: A windows shortcut is the same as a Linux link.